# d3 async await fetch.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, promise

I'm using d3-fetch library to be able to use ***async/await***, however I'm getting following error: fetch.json is not a function.

It does work with d3.json() though.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    async function fetchAllData() {

    try {

        let data = await fetch.json('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cpi9w');
        return data;

        console.log("Initial data: ", data);

        console.log("type of n: ", indicateType(data[0].n));

        let format = d3.timeFormat("%Y");


        //Nesting data by category
        let updatedData = d3.nest()
            .key(d => d.category)
            .sortValues((a, b) =>  a.year - b.year)
            .entries(data);

        //Define xScale domain (min,max assume it has been sorted by year)
        xScale.domain([
            d3.min(updatedData, function(s) { return s.values[0].year; }),
            d3.max(updatedData, function(s) { return s.values[s.values.length - 1].year })
        ]);

        console.log("Nested data: ", updatedData);



        //Draw an SVG for each country

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const indicateType = unevaluatedOperand => typeof unevaluatedOperand;

fetchAllData();
```

Comment: you are using `return` on your second line

Comment: @MaheerAli thank you but I assume this is nothing to do with fetch.json is not a function

Comment: What is fetch? A d3 instance? Did you try with `d3.json()`?

Comment: @Fefux it does work with d3.json but I wanted it to work with async/await

Comment: Still don't know what is `fetch`

Comment: @EdgarKiljak I don't get it. You already got a working solution. Why would you expect it to continue working if you swapped out `d3` for `fetch`? They're totally different beasts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fetch is part of the [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). As per the documentation, calling `fetch.json()` is not the way it works.

Here is a working example:

```js
async function fetchAllData () {
  // await response of a fetch call
  const response = await fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cpi9w');
  // once the promise is resolved convert the response to an object
  const data = await response.json();
  // your data has been converted to an object now)
  console.log('Initial data:', data);
  return data;
}

fetchAllData();
```